# How can send back my own 404 error message in ASP.NET , but as json?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, exception, http-status-code-404, http-response-codes

i'm trying to send back a simple error message as `Json`, with the `HTTP code` as `404`.

So i started out writing my own `IExceptionFilter` that checks to see the exception. To keep this simple, if the exception throw is of type `ResourceNotFoundException` then i set the code to `404`. Otherwise everything else if `500`.

Now, the problem is .. the default IIS7 404 error message is returned :( my code is called .. but it seems to bypass it (later on in the pipeline)...

is there some trick i need to do?

do I need a custom error handling (in the web config) to be turned on or something?

---

Edit:
I'm trying to do what twitter does. Their [Http Response Code documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors) shows / explains some examples how they handle 404's, etc.. and i'm wanting to do that in my MVC app.

Edit 2:
The code i've done is listed [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1471123.aspx), for anyones reference :)

Comment: Is emitting JSON really what you want to do? It wouldn't be better for the receiver to read a 404 status and then handle than internally? I mean, I struggle to see what meaningful data would go into a JSON packet for a 404 that the client doesn't already know.

Comment: Json or Xml. Either way, I need to send back a 404 and the consumer needs to handle it. This is what twitter does, for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you are handling your exception, are you setting ExceptionHandled to true?

Here's a quick example...

```
HandleException(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
  Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

  //Check if our exception has been handled.
  if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled == false)
  {
    //Do your exception stuff
    filterContext.Result = YourExceptionMessageAsAnActionResult();
    //Set it as null.
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I've also added a link to the code i've done. Can u check that out, please?

Comment: I have replied to that message also. It looks like there is a small typo in your code, but I'm sure that this is just a typo in the question code, and not what's in your class.

Comment: yeah, it was just a question typo as i reduced the real logic for berevity. *blush*.